# Change icon for expand collapse in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, font-awesome, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to change icon (i.e plus, minus) on click in expand collapse accordion, I am using `Font Awesome` class for icons. I know it is easily possible with jquery but if there is any way in angularjs, then please let me know.

HTML looks like:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne{{test}}">
  Test
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at `ng-class`.

Short example...

in your template:

```
<span ng-click="flag = !flag" ng-class="{ active : flag }">
  click me!
</span>
```

in your css:

```
.active { color: red; }
```